# Remove hand cursor when over link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a custom cursor on my website, and was able to get rid of the cursor (arrow) by adding this is my CSS.

```
body {cursor: none;}
```

This is gets rid of the cursor, but when I go over a link, the hand shows up to indicate I can click it, I really don't want this and am unsure on how to remove it.

Any Idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a{
cursor:none!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to Remove Hand Cursor

```
a{
    cursor: default;
}
```